# RTL2838 DVB-T2 dongle not working on Ubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu, dvb

I can't get my Walkera Dvb-t2 dongle to work on Ubuntu 18.
`lsusb`
shows
`Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL2838 DVB-T.`
There is also no /dev/dvb directory.
What should I do to make it work?

Update

```
 sudo dmesg | grep dvb
[   45.943415] dvb_core: disagrees about version of symbol vb2_vmalloc_memops
[   45.943417] dvb_core: Unknown symbol vb2_vmalloc_memops (err -22)
[   45.956252] dvb_core: disagrees about version of symbol vb2_vmalloc_memops
[   45.956253] dvb_core: Unknown symbol vb2_vmalloc_memops (err -22)
[ 1033.304738] dvb_core: disagrees about version of symbol vb2_vmalloc_memops
[ 1033.304740] dvb_core: Unknown symbol vb2_vmalloc_memops (err -22)
[ 1033.320396] dvb_core: disagrees about version of symbol vb2_vmalloc_memops
[ 1033.320399] dvb_core: Unknown symbol vb2_vmalloc_memops (err -22)
[ 5795.005693] dvb_core: disagrees about version of symbol vb2_vmalloc_memops
[ 5795.005695] dvb_core: Unknown symbol vb2_vmalloc_memops (err -22)
[ 5795.030806] dvb_core: disagrees about version of symbol vb2_vmalloc_memops
[ 5795.030808] dvb_core: Unknown symbol vb2_vmalloc_memops (err -22)
[ 6396.612446] dvb_core: disagrees about version of symbol vb2_vmalloc_memops
[ 6396.612448] dvb_core: Unknown symbol vb2_vmalloc_memops (err -22)
[ 6396.637432] dvb_core: disagrees about version of symbol vb2_vmalloc_memops
[ 6396.637437] dvb_core: Unknown symbol vb2_vmalloc_memops (err -22)

dmesg | grep "RTL"
[    0.935974] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth0: RTL8105e at 0x        (ptrval), e0:db:55:87:98:0c, XID 00c00000 IRQ 25
[    1.596255] usb 2-1.2: Product: RTL2838UHIDIR
[ 1033.264648] usb 1-1.2: Product: RTL2838UHIDIR
[ 5794.959085] usb 2-1.2: Product: RTL2838UHIDIR
[ 6396.552519] usb 2-1.2: Product: RTL2838UHIDIR
```

Comment: Can you please include anything relevant from a `dmesg`.  Also please elaborate on what way is it "not working"?  No TV? No radio? Can't change channel?  Something else?

Comment: A lot of DVB receivers require a firmware to be uploaded into the driver at start-time (i.e.: boot).  Whenever my DVB cards have failed, this has always been the issue.  These issues are typically found in `dmesg` output.

Comment: I'm surprised that doesn't work. That "disagrees about symbol" means that the driver is built for a different kernel version.  Did you install a driver from somewhere?  Also: do you have the package `ubuntu-firmware-nonfree` installed?

Comment: @Kingsley I don't think the RTL283x needs firmware to be loaded from the host to work, so `ubuntu-firmware-nonfree` shouldn't be necessary or help.

Comment: but I do agree, this looks like the kernel module was built for a different kernel. But then, the version check should definitely kick in and prohibit loading....

Comment: TEX, did you do anything to get that driver? I ask because it should normally be included with linux and you shouldn't have to do anything, but sometimes there's bad guides online...

Comment: All that I did was to build & install Linux TV's media_build git repository